# How to create a 2 cm margin to print?

Tags: html

I want to print a 2 cm margin using html and css instead of Word. So I used this code in my style sheet:

```
body{
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 2cm;
}
```

And when I check for results, there is always a lonely border on the top. The other borders disappear. Why is it happening?
Thank you a lot.

Comment: The element has no height set it, nor does it have any contents. Either add contents, or add height: 100% or height 100vh to your CSS file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add the padding to your body because what you are looking at is full border without any content. See the [example](http://www.codepen.io/rj99/pen/paagkw)
Css:

```
Body{
border:2px solid black;
margin: 2cm;
padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Oh, yeah, that makes sense. Thank you so much!